# How to insert a custom tick mark and a corresponding label on R plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

When creating a plot, R assigns default tick marks for the axes. I wish to insert custom tick marks and labels along the default tick marks. I'd also like to further customise the inserted tick marks and labels (e.g., change size and color) so that they would differ from the default generated ones.

Here's an illustration:

```
library(ggplot2)

x <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
y <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
ggplot() + geom_line(aes(x,y)) + geom_point(aes(x=3.27, y=3.33), size=7, col="turquoise4")
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsKv7.png)

In the picture, the coloured point is the most important piece of data on the graph. As such, the goal is to help the reader easily understand that data point. Ideally, the hand-drawn red tick marks would be thicker than the default ones, have the same colour as the data point, and be accompanied with the corresponding labels (i.e., 3.27 for x axis, and 3.33 for y) - again, same colour as the data point, and bigger in size, comparing to the default ones.

After having checked several resources on axis customisation, it seems that they focus on adjusting all tick marks at once - colour, orientation, size, intervals between tick marks, etc. How to create unique tick marks and labels that differ from the rest remains a mystery for me. Any help is highly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always set your desired breaks via the `breaks` argument of the `scale`, e.g. for your example you could add your custom break and tick to the x axis like so:

```r
library(ggplot2)

x <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
y <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)

base <- ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point(aes(x = 3.27, y = 3.33), size = 7, col = "turquoise4")

base +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(2, 4, 6, 3.27))
```

[image]

For a more general or automatic approach you could add the custom break to the default vector of breaks which are computed via `scales::breaks_extended()`, i.e you could do:

```r
base +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = \(x) c(scales::breaks_extended()(x), 3.27))
```

[image]

Similar you could use the `labels` argument to assign a vector of labels or use a formatter function to add labels to the breaks. For each case one approach to set a color and/or font size for your custom tick only or for a subset of ticks would be to use the `ggtext` package which allows for styling via Markdown, HTML and/or CSS ,e.g. for the manual approach you could do:

```r
library(ggtext)

base +
  scale_x_continuous(
    breaks = c(2, 4, 6, 3.27),
    labels = c(2, 4, 6, "<span style='color: turquoise4; font-size: 20pt'>3.27</span>")
  ) +
  theme(axis.text.x = ggtext::element_markdown())
```

[image]

Finally, for a more general or automatic approach I personally prefer to use some custom functions. Whether such an approach is worthwhile depends however on how often you have or want to use this functionality. Such an approach may look like so:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtext)

label_highlight <- function(x, no_high) {
  x[!x %in% no_high] <- glue::glue(
    "<span style='color: turquoise4; font-size: 20pt'>{x[!x %in% no_high]}</span>"
  )
  x
}

default_breaks <- function(x, expand = .05) {
  scales::breaks_extended()(range(x) + expand * c(-1, 1) * diff(range(x)))  
}

default_x <- default_breaks(x)
default_y <- default_breaks(y)

ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point(aes(x = 3.27, y = 3.33), size = 7, col = "turquoise4") +
  scale_x_continuous(
    breaks = c(default_x, 3.27),
    label = ~ label_highlight(.x, default_x)
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    breaks =  c(default_y, 3.33),
    label = ~ label_highlight(.x, default_y)
  ) +
  theme(
    axis.text.x = ggtext::element_markdown(),
    axis.text.y = ggtext::element_markdown()
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Nifty solution with `ggtext`! I was about to suggest a solution with `geom_rug` which would do nice for the ticks but leaving the labelling a hacky thing though.

Comment: Thank you, @Stefan, I'm impressed, wonderful answer! Could you please elaborate on syntax in `base +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = \(x) c(scales::breaks_extended()(x), 3.27))`? It didn't seem to work for me.

Being new to R, I don't know what I don't know. Do you have any suggestions to learn about different possibilities of a package or function and its inputs? After your reply I checked the unknown inputs in ggplot2 package description on cran.r-project.org, which was useful, but not exhaustive in examples. Maybe there's something better?